# Playwright - why does page.content sometimes return nothing?

Tags: node.js, playwright

In 7/10 times I can access and get the content with page.content(), but in 3/10 approx. times I get nothing back.
I have logged the html I get in both cases (where I get all the page content and where I dont).
In the case where I dont, I only get the static info (header, footer etc), but not the dynamic content. Also in this case I get the cookie banner info which I do not get when I can access all the content (static and dynamic). Could this be the reason? If so what can I do to accept the cookies automatically? If not, what could be the reason?

```
    function getContent = async () => {
      const browser = await {chromium}["chromium"].launch({
                chromiumSandbox: false
      })
      const context = await browser.newContext();
      const page = await context.newPage()

      await page.goto(url, {
      timeout: 10 * 1000,
            waitUntil: 'load'
      })
      const html = await page.content();
      await context.close();
      await browser.close();
        return html;  
   }
```

EDIT: below code leads to 1/10 cases locator.check: Timeout 10000ms exceeded.:

```
const browser = await {chromium}["chromium"].launch({
    chromiumSandbox: false
})
const context = await browser.newContext();
const page = await context.newPage()
await page.goto(url);
await page.waitForLoadState("networkidle");
await page.locator('[name="TRAFFIC"]').check({ timeout: 10 * 1000});

await page.getByRole('section', { name: 'U-Bahn'})

const html = await page.content();
await context.close();
await browser.close();
return html;
```

Comment: may be because that websites loads content using xhr request, try waitUntil: 'networkidle' or you can test to wait 2sec before page.content()

Comment: It's hard to help without the site and a description of why you want the page HTML (is there a specific element in there you're retrieving data from? If so, which?), but yeah, basically you have a race condition. `load` does not wait for all resources to load. See also [Playwright docs -- when is the page loaded?](https://playwright.dev/docs/navigations#when-is-the-page-loaded)

Comment: thank you for replying!! the website Im scraping: https://www.bvg.de/de/verbindungen/stoerungsmeldungen and im sscraping all the reports (its in german). should I remove 'waitUntil: 'load'' then?Is there something else I can add so it does wait?

Comment: As suggested above, it seems like waitUntil Load is not loading the entire content of the page. You can use networkidle as suggested in the first comment. Checkout the code: [Playwright-code](https://try.playwright.tech/?l=javascript&s=kguf0qk)

Comment: Thank you. I have added it. I also checked the website and the content that I need is loaded via fetch, some other content that I dont need is added via xhr, not sure if it still has an affect. I also (please see in my edit) added a locator for the content that I need and specified a timeout. That gives me in about 1/10 cases a timeout err: locator.check: Timeout 10000ms exceeded. so that seems to be the part in the content that loads sometimes too slow. Is it recommended to give a very big timeout number (as 1000 * 1000) ?

Answer (score 0):

> Because page is not fully loaded yet.

To make sure page is fully loaded - verify the element which on page load  **visibly loads last** in the Page:

```
    // Page has navigated to expected URL and 
    //A specific element is visible which loads last in the page visibly
    await page.goto(url)
    await expect(page).toHaveURL(/.*homePage/)
    await expect(page.getByText('Welcome')).toBeVisible({timeout:5000})
```